# Module for Importing and exporting Vcards

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there drupal module to support importing vcard details to the site and publish the details of the content?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [vCard](https://www.drupal.org/project/vcard) module. It can be useful for you.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... adds a vCard download link to every users profile. This link makes it easy to add users on your Drupal site to your local address book. Since we love [microformats](http://microformats.org/), there is also a theme function (theme_vcard) for displaying user data in the [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) format.